# Can I find a potential function in the usual way if the central field contains $t$ in its magnitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm working on a classical mechanics problem in which the problem states that a particle of mass $m$ moves in a central field of attractive force of magnitude:

$$F(r, t) = \frac{k}{r^2}e^{-at}$$

- $r$ is the distance from the force center,
- $t$ is time,
- and $k$, $a$ are constants.

I am concerned about the $t$ in the exponent. I did more than half of the question already (which involves finding lagrangian/hamiltonian equations) using a potential I'm not even sure is correct.

I calculated it by taking the integral of $F(r, t)$ with respect to $r$. It is just that there is a $t$ in the magnitude so I know I shouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Hi @Nosyt, and welcome to [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq)! I've updated you question and add some LaTeX. And if you have doubts in you calculations - add it. Without this it can't be checked on correcteness.

Comment: A time dependent force is not necessarily conservative (usually it is not) so there might no potential exist.

Comment: Nosyt, to clarify: were you given the potential $U(x,t)$, or were you given the force $F$? Or are you using $U$ for the force (which is quite confusing usage)?

Comment: This is a copy and paste of the question from a word file.

My professor often makes mistakes :(

1.  A particle of mass  m  moves in a central field  of attractive force of magnitude (the one written above in latex)   , where k and a are constants, t is the time , and r is the distance  of m from the force center.  (a)  Find the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian functions, (b)  Find Lagrange’s and Hamilton’s equations,  ( c)  Is H the total energy? Give reasons , and (d)  Is H constant of Motion? Give reasons.

Comment: Yes, the one in latex is F NOT U.  The person who edited my post used U but it should be F!  Definitely.

Comment: @Nosyt: please change it back into the more conventional $F$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no potential energy associated with your system as the force is time dependent. However, from your comment I understand that you want to know the

- Lagrangian
- Hamiltonian
- Total energy

A particle which moves under the action of the time-dependent force follows Newton's equation of motion
$$m \ddot r = F(r,t) + m r \omega^2$$
with $$F(r,t)=\frac{k}{r^2}e^{-at}$$ and $\omega$ the angular velocity.

This equation can be seen as the Euler-Lagrange equation of the Lagrangian
$$L= \frac{m \dot r^2}{2} - \frac{l^2}{2 m r^2} - \frac{k}{r} e^{-a t}$$
with $l= m r^2 \omega$ the angular momentum (around the fixed axis of rotation) which is conserved.

The Hamiltonian is then given via a Legendre transform
$$ H = p \dot r -L= \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{l^2}{2 m r^2} + \frac{k}{r} e^{-a t}$$
with $p= \partial L/\partial_{\dot r} = m \dot r .$

The Hamiltonian is also the total energy of the system (which is not conserved).

Comment: Comment to the answer(v1): It should be emphasized  that it's the angular momentum, not the angular velocity, that is a constant of motion.

Comment: @Qmechanic: thank you for the comment. I edited the answer and made this fact explicit.